# Вне очереди вызвать функцию mouseup()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Верстаю таблицу ячеек как у экселя. Сейчас делаю выделение диапазона ячеек.
Проблема заключается в тому, что при зажимании ЛКМ (левую кнопку мыши) у нас `mouseDown = true`и при наведении `.hover()` на ячейку срабатывает функция `selectRange(id)` которая визуально выделяет наш диапазон. 
По задумке при `.mouseup()` у нас `mouseDown = false` и тогда функция не будет выделять диапазон, но `selectRange()` не прекращает работу и когда мы отпускаем ЛКМ при наведении все равно выделяет новый диапазон.

[image: select range]

```js
$('.default')
        .mousedown(function(){
            mouseDown = true;
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            var address = id.slice(8,id.length);
            //select range
            startSelectCell = address;
            selectRange(id);
        })
        .mouseup(function(){
            mouseDown = false;
        })
        .hover(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            if (mouseDown == true) selectRange(id);
        });
function selectRange(id) {
    if (mouseDown == true) {
        var address = id.slice(8,id.length);
        var position = $('#sheet1__'+startSelectCell).position();
        var positionAddress = $('#sheet1__'+address).position();
        var width = positionAddress.left - position.left + cellWidth;
        var height = positionAddress.top - position.top + cellHeight;
        //if (width < 0) positive(width);
        //if (height < 0) positive(height);
        $('.table__select').css({
            display : 'block',
            left : position.left,
            top : position.top,
            width: width,
            height: height
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Непонятно где определён mouseDown - это необходимо сделать явным образом. Далее, проверьте, cрабатывает ли `mouseup` и лучше использовать глобальные обработчики на document или внешнем контейнере с ручным управлением подпиской, а в третьих - выделить обработчик в отдельную функцию, подписывая hover по mousedown. Простой пример:

```
  $(document).mousedown(function() {
      $(".node").bind('mouseover',function(){
          $(this).css({background:"#333333"});
      });
  })
  .mouseup(function() {
    $(".node").unbind('mouseover');
  });

  $('.node').mousedown(function() {
    $(this).css({background:"#333333"});
  });
```

лучше использовать именованые функции. Всё, вместе с mouseDown, поместить в кложуру.

Comment: 11111000000 ,что значит поместить в кложуру?

Comment: @stas.t, в closure

Comment: (function () { ... })()

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю на сколько правильно я поступаю (с точки зрения чистоты и правильности написания кода). Я еще зелёный в js, но ответ @11111000000 подтолкнул меня на такое решение:

```js
$(document).mouseup(function(){
        mouseDown = false;
    });
```

Comment: если это работает, то и хорошо. А в плане стиля и чистоты кода, хороший гайд тут: https://github.com/uprock/javascript